# How can I write a program that when a swipe occurs it draws a line across that frame of the screen and locks it in?

Tags: sprite-kit

How can I get something very similar to this but in spriteKit ?

https://jake.in/trap-the-balls/

Comment: Please be specific when asking problems https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The game link is addictive though!

Comment: You learn sprite kit....... not sure what kind of answer you are expecting